# After change the way to get the elemnt in jQuery the toggleClass doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Hi I had a function which clicking the image which switch '+' and '-' sign and then show or hid the panel. It works if I directly used  the id in function. However I need to modify the function to have parameters which are control id, so it made the function more dynamics. After modified the code the '+' and '-' sign still worked but the panel didn't show. Would someone tell me how to correct my code. Thanks in advance.

The below code is worked:

```
 function ViewPhotoList( ){


            var hd=$("#hdShowPicList").val();
            if (hd == "show") {                
                $("#hdShowPicList").val('hide');
                $("#imgPicListSign").attr("src", imgPlus);                   

            } else {                   
                $("#imgPicListSign").attr("src", imgMin);
                $("#hdShowPicList").val('show');                   
            }
            $("#pnlPhotGird").toggleClass('hide','show');

        }
```

The below code the sign can change but the panel didn't show

```
 function ShowHide(hdID, imgID, pnlID){                

            var hd=$('#'+hdID);
            var hdValue=hd.val();                
            var img= $('#'+imgID);               
            var pnl=$('#'+pnlID);               
            if (hdValue == "show") {                
              hd.val('hide');
                img.attr("src", imgPlus);   
            } else {                   
                img.attr("src", imgMin);
               hd.val('show');                   
            }
            pnl.toggleClass('hide','show');               

        }
```

Comment: Please, add how _ShowHide_ function is invoked.

Comment: @OmarMatijas , There is the code to call the function <asp:Image ID="imgPicListSign" runat="server" onclick="ShowHide('hdShowPicList', 'imgPicListSign', 'pnlPhotGird');" ImageUrl="Images/plus.gif"/>

Comment: have you cheked pnl.length? 
Anyway, i think the original code shouldnt work because toggleClas('hide','show') always should set the class "hide". [http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/] Second parameter is evaluated as bool, and TRUE means class should be on element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is in the last line of code:

```
pnl.toggleClass('hide',(hdValue == "show"));
```